# Why doesn't newly created instance appear from the inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inspector

Use case: Creating a card and adding it on a list of cards.

I'm creating a new instance of a Card and adding it on a list of cards.

```
[SerializeField] private List<Card> _deckCards = new List<Card>();


public void LoadDeck()
{
Card newCard = new Card();
newCard.UpdateCardState(CardState.DECK);
_deckCards.Add(newCard);
}
```

However the deckCards list is displaying the added cards as none from the Unity inspector.

[Screenshot of the insepcted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSDbc.png)

Is there a reason why this happens? thanks!

Comment: FYI That code looks like C#, not UnityScript.

Comment: oh sorry! I thought it was the same. thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

Solved now. Turns out, Card is a class that inherits from Monobehavior.
To fix this, I had to remove Monobehavior and add [System.Serializable] from the top of the Card class.